# Amount of members with a certain role says 1/24 on discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So I have a command that gives people roles and then updates how to give roles. It's a lot of characters in the code and I got a suggestion that told me to use f-strings but I prefer str. Anyway, when I run the command it does everything as intended except instead of saying how many members out of 24 have the role, it says `1/24`. It also does not print any errors.

```py
signer=message.author
signee=message.mentions[0].mention
signeeid=message.mentions[0].id
server=bot.get_guild(920821650096812063)
teamsidslist=[920821650180694104, 920821650201657359, 920821650201657356, 920821650256187495, 920821650180694100, 920821650180694102]
teamnames=['Philadelphia Eagles', 'Los Angeles Rams', 'New England Patriots', 'Dallas Cowboys', 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers', 'San Francisco 49ers']
teamemojis=['AFREagles','AFRRams', 'AFRPatriots','AFRCowboys', 'AFRBucs', 'AFR49ers']
FO = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=920821650285539374)
GM = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=920821650285539373)
HC = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=920821650285539372)
staffroles = [FO, GM, HC]
FA = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=920821650180694097)
Suspended = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=920821650159702055)
roster=[]
agency=[]
teams=[]
for rolesids in message.author.roles:
  if rolesids.id in teamsidslist:
    teams.append(rolesids.id)
    step2=str(teams)
    step3=step2.replace("[","")
    step4=step3.replace("]","")
    print(step4)
    step5=teamsidslist.index(int(step4))
    print(step5)
    emote=discord.utils.get(server.emojis,name=teamemojis[step5])
    teamname=teamnames[step5]
    team = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles,id=int(step4))
for agents in server.members:
  if FA in agents.roles:
    agency.append(agents.id)
if signeeid not in agency:
    embedno = discord.Embed(title="Transaction Failed!", description=None, color=discord.Color.red())
    embedno.add_field(name="This Transaction Couldn't Be Completed.", value="This player is signed already! Have them demand from their team or get released.")
    await message.channel.send(embed=embedno)
elif FO in message.author.roles:
  for guys in server.members:
    if guys.id==signeeid:
      await guys.add_roles(team)
      await guys.remove_roles(FA)
      if Suspended in guys.roles:
        await message.channel.send("This player is signable, but is ineligible as they are suspended.")
  roster.append(guys)
  roster_size=str(len(roster))
  SignEmbed= discord.Embed(title="AFR Transactions", description=None, color=discord.Color.green())
  SignEmbed.add_field(name='Successful Transaction.', value=signee+" has been signed to the "+str(emote)+" "+teamname+"!")
  SignEmbed.add_field(name="Roster Size is now ", value=roster_size+'/24', inline=True)
  await message.channel.send(embed=SignEmbed)
  await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Do you have [`member intents`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html) enabled?

Comment: Yes. Would there be anything else that would make that happen?

Comment: Could you try printing your `roster`, or rather debugging your code by printing different parts of it, such as each 'guys', 'agents', etc.?

Comment: @Bagle When I print the roster it still says 1/24. I don't know if I printed the right part, but I did print(roster_size+'/24'). Let me know if there is anything else you need in order to help me. I appreciate it.